# TextFormField character limit not working

Tags: flutter, dart

***TL;DR** `maxLength` in `TextFormField` sometimes allows more characters than the specified limit. Why does this happen?*

I'm trying to create a `Form` to feed user-inputted data into my app. As part of this, I have a `TextFormField` where I seek to limit the maximum number of characters allowed for input using `maxLength`.

My issue is, while `maxLength` mostly works fine, it seems to be possible to input more characters than the specified limit, particularly when inputting quickly (e.g. pressing digits in rapid succession).
In my code snippet below, I set a `maxLength` of 6 chars, but if you type quickly enough, it's possible to input 7 chars. *i.e. The maximum number possible should be *999,999*, but it's possible to input *9,999,999*.*

**My code snippet**

```
TextFormField(// text form field for inputting a number
            validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Please enter a target to save' : null,

            // Using inputFormatters to only accept digits as inputs
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,],
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,

            // When I specify a maxLength of 6, it can still receive up to 7 digits if entered quickly
            maxLength: 6,

            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                _new_number_to_input = int.parse(val);
              });
            },
          ),
```

I have also tried using the following code as part of `inputFormatters`, however, it doesn't really do what I want.

```
new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(6)
```

I realise that I can also add `val.length < 7` as part of my validator function, but I'm trying to find a less finicky solution. I'm also wondering what other implications this issue posted may have, as I was hoping that form validation would allow me to pretty much trust the integrity of inputted data ~100%.

Is there something wrong with my code above that's resulting in this? What's going on with `maxLength`, and why is it possible to exceed the character limit when typing quickly?

Comment: When you were using `LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter`, have you import the package? `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

Comment: Yes I had imported 'package:flutter/services.dart'; when using  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter

Comment: Add `maxLengthEnforced: true,` to the `TextFormField` along with `maxLength: 6,`

Comment: It looks like both maxLength and LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter are broken at the moment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67898

Comment: @Uwe Keim Managed to solve? I have the same problem ...

Comment: I was the one who edited the question, not the one who asked 

Answer (score 1):

Add `maxLengthEnforced: true,` to the `TextFormField` along with `maxLength: 6,`.

Small Example:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      autovalidate: true,
      onChanged: () {
        Form.of(primaryFocus.context).save();
      },
      child: Wrap(
        children: List<Widget>.generate(5, (int index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size(200, 50)),
              child: TextFormField(
                maxLength: 6,
                maxLengthEnforced: true,
                onSaved: (String value) {
                  print('Value for field $index saved as "$value"');
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Referenced from [TextFormField Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for this, I never realised that 'maxLengthEnforced' was a thing! However, it seems like the problem still persists. I'm still able to go 1 digit more than the limit specified in maxLength.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. `maxLength' is enforced with numbers, but not letters.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. It only works with a number, not letters

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a inputformatter specifiying the max char limit to the textfield

```
TextField(
...
...
maxLength: <must be greater than 0>,
 inputFormatters: [
                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(6),
                  ],
    );
```

The input formatter requires you to import the services

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

The [maxLength] must not be null or -1, If it is null or -1 then no limit is enforced.